# Javascript regex to find opening tags at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I am looking for a Javascript regex to find **opening tags at** the **end** of a string. I want to find all opening tags (with no other regular text in between) followed only by other opening tags or no string till the end.

Example String: `<b>sds</b>This is a<u> test.<br><b><span class="test">`;

Desired result `<b><span class="test">`

**EDIT**: To clarify: I do have to handle a string that contains partial html content. It is a chunk of not in itself valid html. Therefor i cannot operate on dom nodes. Because of the fact that i am in a very special environment i do not have nested tags nor invalid tags - just regular inline tags (and even there `u,b,i,span,sup,sup,img,br` only).

I am open to solutions not including a regex, but i am not able to work with dom nodes here.

Comment: Why don't you want to include `<br>`?

Comment: @Cerbrus Perhaps because `br` doesn't take a closing tag, and so isn't open?

Comment: Obligatory [_"Don't parse HTML with R̶egex̧es"_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) comment.

Comment: @Cerbrus Obligatory and -- in this case -- absolutely correct.

Comment: @PaulRoub / OP: And how is a Regex supposed to know what is, and isn't a valid HTML tag that _does_ require a closing tag? _(Don't parse HTML with Regexes!)_

Comment: @Cerbrus Via a big, unwieldy, `|`-separated list of tags, of course. *(Don't parse HTML with Regexes!)*

Comment: i know that it is not recommened to parse html with regexes, but i am working with a wysiwyg editor and in order to fix broken bahaviour it ccan't be helped and need to work with a html string. The valid tags are known (there are just some that are used in this special environment)

Comment: I think the point is you won't be able to use regex alone to identify which tags haven't been closed

Comment: What @Donutttt said. You can't write a _reliable_ regex to do that, that can't be broken with some sort of string.

Comment: @Cebrus: even when the tag attributes are strongly limited?

Comment: @Cebrus: can you show an example for such a case where it is not possible to use a regex?

Comment: Then I'd first have to write a comprehensive regex that I'd be breaking. No thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you are looking for is:

```
(?:<(?!(?:[hb]r|img|link|other_self_closing_tags)\b)\w+\b[^">]*(?:"[^"]*"[^">]*)*>)+$
```

details:

```
(?:
    <                # start of the tag
    (?!  # lookahead assertion (not followed by)
        (?:[hb]r|img|link|other_self_closing_tags)
        \b # word boundary
    )
    \w+ \b # tag name
    [^">]* # all that is not a " or a >
    (?:"[^"]*"[^">]*)* # quoted substrings (to deal with attributes)
    >
)+
$   # end of the string
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more what this regex does - unfortunalety i am not very experienced to write/read regex

Comment: That fails for `"<b>sds</b>This is a test.<br><b><test><span class="test">"`. `<test>` isn't a valid HTML tag, yet it matches: `"<b><test><span class="test">"`

Comment: @Cerbrus: there cannot be a <test>-tag ever (in my special xysiwyg editor environment). 
There can only be the following inline tags: b, u, i, span, sub, sup and li and nothing else

Comment: What if a user literally types in `<test>`?

Comment: then the '<' will be coded in the string as '&lt;' - so no problem

Comment: So, _why_ do you even need to catch these opening tags in the first place, if user can't manually enter HTML?

Comment: On `<b>This is a <b>sample text</b>. This sure is one great sample text.</b>` it matches `<b><b>`. I don't see what you can do with this. Which proves the point that regex are a waste of time here.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil: this case cannot happen because we do not allow nested tags inside our editor

Comment: @JacqueGoupil: https://regex101.com/r/jP1vE2/1

Comment: @Casimir: correct, Jacques string doesn'T even have an opening tag at the end so no match is found

Comment: @Thariama: Once again, __why__ do you need to catch these opening tags? This looks like an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: I think he is cutting the text into parts for some reasons (for example to build an excerpt).

Comment: So, use the DOM instead of sting manipulation.

Comment: Cerbrus: i cannot use the dom manipulations here.

Comment: i updated my question in order to clarify some points here

Comment: This is a WYSIWYG editor in a browser, right? Then you _can_ use DOM manipulation. Browsers are _built_ precisely to do what you're trying to do manually. Use that. Your problem isn't that you need to get the stray HTML start tags, it is that you're getting the part of the text incorrectly. -> XY problem.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't see how DOM or XML Parsers can help here. OP is working on "known broken HTML fragments" and tries to find out about opening tags for instance (every parser will fix that beforehand for instance). So I guess operating with regular expression can be a valid thing here.

Comment: The problem is that the OP has gotten an incorrect snippet in the first place. An X/Y problem. This question is asking for a workaround to that problem.

Comment: @Cerbrus: it is not important why i only got an incomple html fragment as string. Under my special circumstances i do not see why a regex is not suitable. If i would not have my special enviroment regulations i would totally agree to the statement "don't use regex on html".

Comment: How is that not important? If you'd have gotten a proper HTML fragment in the first place, you wouldn't even have to mess with regexes.

Comment: It looks like I actually found a solution using the DOM (And a regex, but not quite to parse HTML elements ;-) )

Comment: [(Here)](https://fiddle.jshell.net/wnmtfc3p/) will add as answer if the question gets re-opened.

Comment: nice thought, but it won't work for <b>sds</b>This is a test.<br><u>ccc<i><b><span class="test">. this would result in <u>ccc<i><b><span class="test"> and the '<u>ccc' is unwanted

Comment: ... Damnit. So, how do you handle tags like that `<u>` then?

Comment: hmm, the regex by Casimir et Hippolyte seems to treat it as desired

Answer (score 1):

It's not only that you should - you can't. Regex can capture groups and look for them again later in the string, so in theory you could find matching HTML tags. Finding which ones DON'T have a match - or trying to find pairs of tags in a non-conforming HTML code - seems rather complex. You also need to ignore all attributes and attribute names. This is quickly getting out of hand.

But where Regex clearly cannot solve this for you is when you have multiple of the same tags, and when you might have invalid crossing tags like `<b><i>Sample text</b></i>`. I don't think it's possible to work out every exception case, but I think it's safe to say that if it's possible to do it in a single regex, it would take a lot of time to run and forever to write.

Plus if you need to detect auto-closing elements written without the ending `/>`, that makes things even less doable considering new elements are added to HTML every now and then and your code wouldn't be able to deal with them.

Your best bet is to use DOM manipulation if you want to fix something. Or create good HTML in the first place.

EDIT: Even well formed documents are impossible to work with as there's no way to find which tag matches which when there are multiple instances of the same tag in a row. Example: http://regexr.com/3c2mb

Comment: there are no invalid crossing tags in that string and at the execution point of code i got only a string and no DOM objects

Comment: your regex doent't take into accoutn that i want to look for opening tags at the end of a string only